# Usage of custom CSS in Angular2 gives "Can't bind since not native property" error

Tags: css, angular

**My CSS**

```
ol.progress[data-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }
```

I want to use the above in **my template** like this:

```
<ol class="progress" data-steps=4>

   <li *ngFor..> </li>
```

**I tried**:

```
<ol class="progress" [data-steps]="myNg2Variable">
```

**Get errors**:

> Template parse errors:
>       Can't bind to 'data-steps' since it isn't a known native property

How to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the attr property with interpolation:

```
<ol class="progress" attr.data-steps="{{myNg2Variable}}">
```

Cheers

Comment: you can also use "by value" notation `<ol [attr.data-steps]="myNg2Variable">`